# Where is the RenderObject class for the Text widget in the Flutter source code

Tags: flutter, dart, text-widget

I'm researching how the Text widget works in Flutter. I know that the widgets are just blueprints. It is the Element that implements the widget. And the element makes a RenderObject to layout and paint the widget on the screen. I think that's how it works anyway.

- The source code for the Text widget is easy to find. It's [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/text.dart).
- There are also text related style classes in the Flutter engine [here](https://github.com/flutter/engine/blob/master/lib/ui/text.dart).
- And the low level text library classes in C/C++ are [here](https://github.com/flutter/engine/tree/master/third_party/txt/src/txt).

But I can't seem to find anything called a `RenderText`. Who is doing the text rendering? What is its Element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found it. It is called [`RenderParagraph`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/paragraph.dart), not `RenderText`. The `Text` widget creates a `RichText` widget in its build method. `RenderParagraph` is the `RenderObject` corresponding to the `RichText` widget. Another important class is [`TextPainter`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/text_painter.dart), which is used by `RenderParagraph` to coordinate painting the paragraph text. The painting itself is done even lower down in the [LibTxt](https://github.com/flutter/engine/tree/master/third_party/txt/src/txt) library in C/C++.